# Nginx: try_fiiles directive with variable from path

Tags: nginx, regex

I have set up a server block that looks like this:

```
root /var/www/platform

location / {
 index index.html;
}

location /contact {
 try_files $uri /contact.html;
}
```

This works fine. I can go to `x.com/contact` and the `contact.html` page loads.

Now I want to add a subdirectory `products` with files like `product1.html` and so on. When the user goes to `x.com/products/product1` I want to load the html file.

Because the `products` subdir is within the `platform` directory, `x.com/products/product1.html` works fine with the current ^ setup. I just want to get rid of the need to have `.html` at the end.

So I try adding a location block

```
location /products/(product) {
 root /products;
 try_files /$1.html $1.html /index.html;
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

If there's another better (but still easy) approach, I'd love to know it too.

Comment: Simplest solution is to use `root /;` with `try_files $uri $uri.html /index.html;` and place it inside `location /products/ { ... }`

Comment: Thank you! So `$uri` is the part after the location.. saves a lot of trouble. Can you please explain briefly - what was wrong the way I tried?

Comment: No. `$uri` is the current URI and includes the `/products` prefix, which is why you need to remove it from `root` within the `location /products` block. Your version would have worked if you used the correct syntax for a [regular expression `location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Answer (score 0):

Richard basically answered the question in the comments (I am writing this to remove the question from the list of unanswered ones). The solution that worked is adding this location block instead:

```
location /products/ {
 try_files $uri $uri.html /index.html
}
```